# How to search or filter a column in C# datagrid view, datagridview source is a list

Tags: c#, datagridview

I use dapper to get a joined data from database, then store as a list, and use datagridview to display list,
Now I want to search a column by a textbox,

```
   private void SetupDataTableAvailableTool() {
        toolList = adapter.GetJoinedToolsData();
        dgvAvailableTools.DataSource = null;
        dgvAvailableTools.DataSource = toolList;
        }
```

above code is display list in dgvAvailableTools.

```
        List<Tools> toolFilterList = new List<Tools>();
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();           
        bs.Filter = searchTextBox.Text;
        dgvAvailableTools.DataSource = bs;
```

above solution is not working .

I tried below

```
(dgvAvailableTools.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =string.Format("Name='{0}'", searchTextBox.Text);
```

it give me an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object,
I tried to create datatable , but it is not working, code at below

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Products");
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

can anyone tell me the solution? I dont need binding data to datagridview.
Thanks in advnace

Answer (score 0):

When using a BindingSource filter you need to include the property name e.g. in this case `Item` is the property to `filter` on.

```
private void FilterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTextBox.Text))
    {
        _customerBindingSource.RemoveFilter();
    }
    else
    {
        _customerBindingSource.Filter = $"Item = '{searchTextBox.Text}'";
    }
}
```

[image]

> how can I transfer this list to BindingSource bs

The code above sets a DataTable to the BindingSource were in this case _operations.CustomerDataTable is returns a DataTable.

- See this [code](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/windows-forms-csharp/blob/Version3/DataGridViewComboBasicsNonEntityFramework/Form1.cs#L97) for assignment
- [Code](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/windows-forms-csharp/blob/Version3/DataGridViewComboBasicsNonEntityFramework/Classes/Operations.cs#L28:L41) which reads the data

Werther using a DataTable or a DataAdapter its semantics.

See also [BindingSource Filter with Starts, contains, ends with and case sensitive options](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53413.bindingsource-filter-with-starts-contains-ends-with-and-case-sensitive-options.aspx)

Comment: Hi Karen, thanks, , toolList = adapter.GetJoinedToolsData(); how can I transfer this list to BindingSource bs ?

Comment: See the last section of my reply which I just added content. Also, a link to an article on BindingSource filtering which includes starts with, ends with and contains.

Comment: now I have transfer list to bindingsource, but filter still not working,             BindingSource bs = new BindingSource() { DataSource = toolList };
         
            bs.Filter = $"productName = '{ tbxToolName.Text}'";      when I input in textbox, the data grid view will insert an empty row after previous data grid view.

Comment: Typically used in complex data-binding scenarios, the Filter property allows you to view a subset of the DataSource. Only underlying lists that implement the IBindingListView interface support filtering.  I dont implement the IBindingListView interface. that is why not  working.

Comment: I have a [code sample](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/windows-forms-csharp/blob/Version3/LoadDataGridViewProgressBar/BindingListForm.cs#L54:L69) which loads a list into a BindingList then the BindingList is set to the BindingSource.DataSource. Filtering is done with a secondary BindingList.  If the search text box is empties the filter is removed.